# Record the date when EF migration was applied

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Code-First Entity Framework context and I'm going to update database using Entity Framework migrations mechanism. For my particular application I need to be able to tell when particular migration was applied to particular database. To make this more fool-proof I want to write that code once for all the migrations that I'm going to have in the future, without having to modify each automatically generated Migration file.

I've tried two options:

1. Introduce 'Migration' class-in-between in the same namespace where all migrations are going to be created. Since generated migrations do not specify the full name of the EF Migration class, they will automatically pick up my own Migration class where I can override few things, like `Up()` and `Down()` method. The problem with this approach is that automatically created 'Up/Down' methods do not call respective base methods.
2. Create my own override of `HistoryRepository` like this:

```
internal class MyHistoryRepository : SqlServerHistoryRepository
{
    // Constructor omitted

    protected override void ConfigureTable(EntityTypeBuilder<HistoryRow> history)
    {
        base.ConfigureTable(history);
        history.Metadata.AddProperty("ApplicationDate", typeof(DateTime))
            .SetValueGeneratorFactory((property, type) => new  CurrentDateTimeValueGenerator());

    }
```

This code extends history table with the column I need, however I was unable to make this generator working, it doesn't set DateTime.Now into new entries as I hoped.

Any ideas on how to make these working or what better approach to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to to configure database to generate current time for new column:

```cs
protected override void ConfigureTable(EntityTypeBuilder<HistoryRow> history)
{
    base.ConfigureTable(history);
    history.Metadata.AddProperty("ApplicationDate", typeof(DateTime))
        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I changed two things:
1. Instead of `HasDefaultValueSql` I used `SetDefaultValueSql`, I don't know if that's different version or something, but that's the method I have
2. I used "getUtcDate()" to have dates in UTC format to avoid some timezone-related problems in the future.